# flatening the arrays inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array of objects to each object there is a property called app is there, i need to filter with another array if the check array has the same app then filter and get that one only.

I am able to get it but my problem is i am getting as nested array i need to get a single array of 4 objects.

Please see the below code. Also is there any other way to have the expected output.

```js
let data = [{
  app: "test1",
  key: 1
}, {
  app: "test2",
  key: 2
}, {
  app: "test1",
  key: 3
}, {
  app: "test2",
  key: 3
}]

let checkArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

let result = checkArr.map(ch => data.filter(da => da.app === ch))

console.log(result)
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{
    "app": "test1",
    "key": 1
}, {
    "app": "test1",
    "key": 3
}, {
    "app": "test2",
    "key": 2
}, {
    "app": "test2",
    "key": 3
}]
```

Comment: `filter` returns an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `.filter` to filter the data object array

```js
let data = [{app: "test1", key: 1}, {app: "test2", key:2}, {app: "test1", key:3}, {app: "test2", key:3}]

let checkArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];


var arr = data.filter(o => checkArr.indexOf(o.app) > -1);

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: That's a simple one, thanks for the quick response, also instead of indexOf we can use includes isn't

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes you can :) you can accept and upvote the answer if this resolved your query

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (not supported by IE/Edge):

```js
let data = [{app: "test1", key: 1}, {app: "test2", key:2}, {app: "test1", key:3}, {app: "test2", key:3}]

let checkArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

let result = checkArr.flatMap(ch => data.filter(da => da.app === ch))

console.log(result)
```

Or flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
let data = [{app: "test1", key: 1}, {app: "test2", key:2}, {app: "test1", key:3}, {app: "test2", key:3}]

let checkArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

let result = [].concat(...checkArr.map(ch => data.filter(da => da.app === ch)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:

```
let data = [{app: "test1", key: 1}, {app: "test2", key:2}, {app: "test1", key:3}, {app: "test2", key:3}]

let checkArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

let result = data.filter(item => {
    return checkArr.indexOf(item.app)!== -1
})

console.log(result)
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9vL7ohg/5/

Answer (score 1):

With `map` you first associate to each name in `checkArr` the array `data.filter(...)`of all the apps matching that name.

If you want to flatten this array, the clearest way is to concatenate all the results with a `reduce`:

```
checkArr
    .map(name => data.filter(d => d.app === name))
    .reduce((a,b) => [...a, ...b]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected output doesn’t appear to be a flattened array. It appears to be the output of

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

To do your filtering, you would change the predicate:

```
data.filter((d) => checkArr.indexOf(d.app) !== -1);
```

To flatten arrays, I would tend to go with

```
data.reduce((a, innerArray) => {
  a.push(...innerArray);
  return a;
}, []);
```

This will start with an empty array and incrementally add all of the elements of the subarrays to it. The `...` prefix operator on an array converts it to an expanded list of the elements, which are passed into `push` for insertion without their array wrapper.